# Inverse Laplace Transform of $F(s) = \frac{(3s^2+9s+14)*e^{-5s}}{(s^3+4s^2+7s)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

Find the inverse Laplace Transform of $F(s) = \frac{(3s^2+9s+14)*e^{-5s}}{(s^3+4s^2+7s)}$

I have found the Simplified $F(s) = (\frac2s+\frac{s+1}{(s+2)^2+3})*e^{-5s}$

I am having trouble figuring out the inverse transform from this point on 
(I think you have to use $(F(s)*e^{-at})$

How would you go about solving the rest of the transform, knowing which formulas to use.

$e^{-2t}\cos(\sqrt{3}t) - e^{-2t}\sin(\sqrt{3}t) + 2U(t-5)$

Comment: Okay I think I got not to sure about the last term though

Comment: $e^{-2t}cos(srt(3)t) - e^{-2t}sin(sqrt(3)t) + 2U(t-5)$

Comment: Isnt $\frac{s+1}{(s+2)^2+3} = \frac{(s+2) +1 -2}{(s+2)^2+3}$ then this is split in to two terms and then its straight forward following the formula from there

Comment: And I just wanted to says thanks for your patience and awesome for helping me learn these transforms :)

Comment: Yes, we have $e^{-5 s}\left(\dfrac{2}{s} + \dfrac{s+2}{(s-(-2))^2 + \sqrt{3}^2} -\dfrac{1}{(s-(-2))^2 + \sqrt{3}^2}\right)$. Now recall, after finding the ILT, we have to change $t = t-5$ and include a unit step for the shift, so $e^{-2t}$ becomes $e^{-2(t-5)}$ and that is where the $10$ I showed earlier came from. This is from transform 27 I linked to.

Comment: The final form should be $2 u (t-5) -\frac{1}{3} e^{10-2 t} u(t-5) \left(\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\sqrt{3} (t-5)\right)-3 \cos \left(\sqrt{3} (t-5)\right)\right)$. In your solution, you forgot to divide by a $\sqrt{3}$ and you forgot to account for the shift term.